# Reliable way to place char directly after array

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using following code to read from socket:

```
char buf[4097];
int ret = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
buf[ret] = 0x0;
std::cout << buf << "\n";
```

However, I don't like the need for `4097` and `sizeof(buf) - 1` in there. It's that kind of stuff that's easy to forget. So I wonder, is there some nice way to force compiler to but `0x0` directly on stack right after the array?

What I would love is something like

```
char buf[4096];
char _ = 0x0;
int ret = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
buf[ret] = 0x0;
std::cout << buf << "\n";
```

but I have no idea how to force compiler to not but anything in between (afaik `#pragma pack` works only on structures, not on stack).

Comment: Like... `char buf[4097] = {0};`? It's called "initialization"...

Comment: `char _ ` is not valid. You cant name the char like that.

Comment: If you're programming in C++, then please use only that tag, even if parts of the question could relate to C. C and C++ are for the most parts two *very* different languages, with *very* different semantics.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer A single underscore is a legal symbol. As is two, three or more. The only restriction is that names beginning with two underscores are reserved for the compiler and standard library in all scopes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. my point is that I want to avoid the need to remember the `- 1` part in `sizeof(buf) - 1`.. I guess I could turn it around into something like `#define BUF_SIZE 4096 ; char buf[BUF_SIZE + 1]; ... read(... BUF_SIZE)`..

Comment: Then you want to remember to put an extra variable after each array? Doesn't sound much better.

Comment: If the data is string (and your code is hinting it is), use `fgets`. But yes, the motivation is not convincing.

Comment: @Gerhardh I would do that by some macro, not by hand; like `char BUFFER(buf, 4096);` would expand into `char buf[4096]; char _ = 0x0;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `A single underscore is a legal symbol. As is two, three or more.` I agree that single underscore is legal, but surely not *two, three or more* (except for the compiler or the standard library).  All such identifiers are `beginning with two underscores`, are they not?

Comment: @user2079303 They are only reserved by the specification, there's nothing in the compilers that need to enforce it.

Comment: You are reading into a buffer, without necessarily reading the entire buffer. Zero-termination appears to be required at runtime-dynamic offsets anyway, so even if it were possible to place a sentinel after the array, it would in the majority of cases not be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd keep things simple:

```
ssize_t read_and_put_0(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)
{
    ssize_t ret = read(fd, buf, count - 1);
    if (ret != -1) // Or `if (ret <= 0)`
        ((char *)buf)[ret] = 0x0;
    return ret;
}

// ...

char buf[4097];
read_and_put_0(fd, buf, sizeof buf);
```

Comment: I don't understand why it would not work (if `_` would be right after `buf`); if `ret == sizeof(buf)`, it would fill whole buffer with data and the `buf[ret] = 0` would set the `_` to `0x0`. So it should work without crashing... I think I'm missing something :/

Comment: @Paladin `_` right after `buf` is _after_ in source code.  The compiler may not locate the two variables in memory as you hope.

Comment: @Paladin What if `ret < sizeof buf`? Imagine `read` reads 1 byte into `buf[0]` and returns `1`. The terminating `0x0` should be placed into `buf[1]`, which is what  `buf[ret] = 0x0;` does. On the other hand, `char _ = 0x0;` essentially would be `buf[sizeof buf]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) would be better used with a `size_t count` and a test to handle if `count==0`..

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh, that I understand. Sorry, I should've been clearer about the second snippet. I would look like `char buf[4096]; char _ = 0x0; int ret = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)); buf[ret] = 0x0; std::cout << buf << "\n";`, that should do what I want, correct? (ignoring the fact I don't know how to enforce `_` right after `buf`)

Comment: @chux Oops. Changed it to `size_t`.

Comment: @Paladin Oh. I guess initializing `_` to `0x0` confused me.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't like the need for `4097` and `sizeof(buf) - 1` in there

Simplicity is beautiful:

```
constexpr std::size_t size = 4096;
char buf[size + 1];
int ret = read(fd, buf, size);
buf[ret] = 0x0;
```

You specify exactly the size that you need, no neet to do manual adding. And there's need for neither sizeof, nor subtracting 1.

Remembering the + 1 for terminator is easier in my opinion than remembering to declare a separate character object - which can't be forced to be directly after the array anyway.

That said, there are less error prone ways to read a text file than `read`.

Answer (score 1):

The relative location in memory of the values of distinct variables in unspecified.  Indeed, some variables might not reside in memory at all.  If you want to ensure relative layout of data in memory then use a struct or class.  For example:

```
struct {
    char buf[4096];
    char term;
} tbuf = { { 0 }, 0 };

int ret = read(fd, tbuf.buf, sizeof(tbuf.buf));
if (ret >= 0 && ret < sizeof(tbuf.buf)) {
    tbuf.buf[ret] = '\0';
}
```

The members of the struct are guaranteed to be laid out in memory in the same order that they are declared, so you can be confident that the fail-safe terminator `tbuf.term` will follow `tbuf.buf`.  You cannot, however, be confident that there is no padding between.  Furthermore, this is just a failsafe.  You still need to write the null terminator, as shown, in case there is a short read.

Additionally, even though the representation of `tbuf` is certain to be larger than its `buf` member by at least one byte, it still produces UB to access `tbuf.buf` outside its bounds.  Overall, then, I don't think you gain much, if anything, by this.

Comment: Would it still be UB if I combined it with `#pragma pack(push, 1)` to make sure there is no padding between `buf` and `term`?

Comment: @Paladin, yes. Accessing an array outside its bounds produces UB, period.  That may turn out to manifest in a harmless way, but that is, again, undefined.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to HolyBlackCats answer that doesn't require giving the size argument as long as you have the array and not a pointer to some array.

```
template <size_t N> ssize_t read_and_put_0(int fd, char (&buf)[N]) {
    ssize_t ret = read(fd, buf, N - 1);
    if(ret != -1) // Or `if (ret <= 0)`
        buf[ret] = 0x0;
    return ret;
}

char buf[4097];
read_and_put_0(fd, buf);
```